# Jordan Canonical Form of $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a $5 \times 5$ invertible matrix over $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose
>   $c_A(x)=(x+1)^3(x+2)^2$ and $m_A(x)=(x+1)(x+2)^2$, what is a Jordan
>   Canonical Form of $A^{-1}$?

Is it possible to obtain a JCF of $A^{-1}$ from that of $A$, or we have to explicitly solve for $c_{A^{-1}}(x)$ and $m_{A^{-1}}(x)$ in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to see that 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-2&1&0&0&0\\
0&-2&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

so we see

$$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{1}{4}&0&0&0\\
0&-\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can't you only assume that there is some matrix $B$ such that $BAB^{-1}$ is equal to the matrix you have up there?

Comment: Thanks but could you elaborate a bit more on it please? Why is the 2-1 entry $-\frac{1}{4}$, isn't it just $1$?

Comment: To Find the inverse of a 2 by 2 matrix, one divides by the determinant, which in this case is $4$.